# Regular expression to verify that string contains a separator comma ( , ) but not a point ( . )

Tags: regex, soapui, assertion

I'm using SoapUI and I have responses of JSON which contains strings.

For example about string "84,96". I need to create a regular expression which verifies that all value decimals of this JSON are containing a comma (`,`) but not a point (`.`)

Examples:
`"84,96"` is Good
`"84.96"` is wrong

Comment: Something like `^\d*,\d*$`?

Comment: what assertion are you using?

Answer (score 0):

```
^(\d+?,?\d+)$
```

this solves your question test here [Test](https://regex101.com/r/p3ty1y/5)

Answer (score 0):

**Numbers**

```
84,96 <-- good
84.96 <-- bad
```

**REGEXEP:**

```
\d+,\d+
```

**Explanation:**

```
\d+ <= All Numbers (84)
,   <= Only Comma  (,)
\d+ <= All Numbers (96)
```

**Result:**

```
84,96
```

**Test Here:** https://regex101.com/r/7NNRZy/1